# Magento Grid - Products Collapsed Vertically

Tags: css, magento-1.7

I have added to many products in Magento Site but when User clicks on any category
then products with more than 3 items collapsed vertically,
Can any one suggest me any solution?

http://onlyresult.com/ec/mag2/mag/index.php/keyboard.html?limit=9

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I have solved by removing all html tags in short description, short description does not allow html formatting.